# Is $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^3+px+q - y^2)$ integral over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, polynomial-rings, integral-extensions

> Let $ B = \mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^3+px+q - y^2)$ and $A = \mathbb{Z}[x]$. I want to know whether the ring extension $A \subset B$ is integral or not.

There can be two possibilities: $x^3+px+q$ is irreducible or is not irreducible.

It's enough to understand whether $y$ is integral.
If we find a finitely generated $A$-module $C$ such that $A[y] \subset C \subset B$ then $y$ is integral.
We can try to find a faithful finitely-generated $A[y]$-module $M$ then $y$ is integral as well.

I see that there is a ring of integer polynomials that are not zero on a cubic curve. Geometric interpretation gives me no clue, alas.

Comment: $B=A[y]$ and $y$ is a zero of $X^2-r$ for some $r \in A$, so the extension seems integral?

Comment: @Mindlack Why is $y^2-r$ = 0?

Comment: Isn’t it the definition with $r=x^3+px+q$?

Comment: @Mindlack Does it mean that any polynomial instead of $x^3+px+q$ can be applied and the extension still will be integral?

Comment: It is an integral extension, but not necessarily an integral domain: these are two unrelated notions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element $y\in B$ is integral over $A$ by definition of $B$ as the quotient of $B:=A[y]/(y^2-r)$ with $r=x^3+px+q$. It follows that the subring of $A[y]\subset B$ is integral over $A$, and clearly $A[y]=B$.